# I need help interpreting this PCA plot

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, pca, plotting

I have a dataset of 116 observations and 10 numeric variables. The dataset contains information about healthy patients and patients attained with breast cancer. I did a PCA plot showing the cluster of healthy/sick patients to see the relation they had with the variables but to my surprise the "N/A (breast cancer patient) cluster" is very far away from any variable. What could that possibly mean ? I'm fairly new to PCA or how to read the plots so any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Here is the picture of the plot : https://imgur.com/a/PO6zfk1

Comment: Does "NA" mean 'Not Available' data (as it usually does) ?

Also, have you included the "sick/healthy" (i.e. class variable) as a column in you PCA data ?

Variable vectors in the line of the class vector would mean they are strongly related with it; while variable vectors perpendicular to the class vector are unrelated.  So, if "classification" is your variable with values "sick" or "healthy", then "Insulin", "HOMA" and "Glucose" are strongly related to the health.